# Absolute positions in mpld3 graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, mpld3

I'm trying to define a custom plugin for [`mpld3`](https://mpld3.github.io/), and I'm struggling with positions. More particularly, by default, SVG generated by `mpld3` come with `Move` and `Zoom` buttons, which change the view of the graph. When I was trying to display things (like text), I stumbled upon a strange behavior where positions are set **relatively** to the current view. It means that if I display a text next to a point `A(10,10)` and then move the view, the point will still be at `(10,10)` but the text will move because its position is relative to the current view.

So I wanted to think again and start with a minimal example which should work : [this example](https://mpld3.github.io/examples/mouse_position.html) from the `mpld3` documentation. In the demo, you can see the behavior I want : positions are absolute (when you move the view, cursor position is set according to the grid).[image].

But if I copy-paste the **exact same code** in Pycharm and execute it, positions are relative to the view which is even more strange : [image]

My guess is it's a *version* problem. I don't know which versions are used in the hosted demo example. I use `mpld3==0.5.1`, `matplotlib==3.2.1` and `numpy==1.19.2`.

Do you have an idea so I can manage to deal with **absolute** positions like in the example ?

Comment: `ax.text(15,15,'test')`I added this code and saw the sample code you showed working in my environment. The 'test' moves in conjunction with the image. Is this what you want?

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you for your comment. Elements added in `pyplot` like `ax.text()` are set *before* the `mpld3` conversion to Javascript, so they move in conjunction with the image like I want. My problem is for *dynamically added* elements with `mpld3` plugin system. For example, in the example, mouse position is displayed in the bottom right corner. If you run the example in your environment, can you tell me if the mouse position is *absolute* or *relative* ? (it's relative if it's in range `([10-20], [10-20])` no matter the moving or zooming of the view)

Comment: When the image is at (10,10) the coordinates are relatively correct, but after you move the image, the position of the mouse is a little off.

Comment: Yup, that's my concern ! And on the website there's no problem.

Comment: I think I get the intent of your question. Certainly the site you presented showed the correct coordinates when the image was moved. I can't help you with this resolution, but I'm sure you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work. It turns out that downgrading `mpld3` to version `0.3` does what I want. I'm sure there is a better solution (because I can't take advantage of the latest version) but it gets the job done.